# 50'C HDD S.M.A.R.T info and HDD temps invisible on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers

I have migrated SATA HDD's from a Windows 7 PC (AMD FX) to a build  Windows 10 21H1 (Ryzen + Gygabite 399 designare). All 5 disks are have no S.M.A.R.T. info and temperature. The disks are accessed OK by Windows 10 and have been checked on another PC, although the feel way too hot on the windows 10 Ryzen machine: 50'C on idle.

Please help
[image]

Comment: Have you tried other software other than that one particular piece of software? [Have you updated HD Tune?](http://www.hdtune.com/) Something that has been updated recently will do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated it, same issue persists. Then I updated the SATA and chipset drivers of the mainboard, same problem.

Comment: What type of SATA cable are you using? I assume SATA III?

Comment: Yes SATA III and the cables were working fine on the other PC. I've just upgraded W10 from 21H1 to 21H2, same problem.